# What is the relationship between singularities for complex times and high frequency asymptotics?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

As said in a [paper](http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v23/i5/p2673_1) I am reading on p 2677 in the text directly above FIG3, this should be a standard result about Fourier transforms of analytic functions. In the paper the authors use these methodes to investigate the intermittent behaviour of turbulent flows kicking in at high frequencies.

But I am not familiar with this, so can somebody explain to me how exactly these singularities in the complex time plane are related to the high frequency behaviour of a function?

Comment: I can't say without reading more context, but this smells like a stationary phase argument: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation

Comment: Sorry, the Wikipedia article's not very good. Here are two resources that might be more helpful: http://www.math.ku.dk/~gimperlein/dif11/dif11_kim_stationaryphase.pdf and http://www.tricki.org/article/How_to_use_the_method_of_stationary_phase_to_control_oscillatory_integrals

Comment: You linked to a 33 page article. You can at least tell us on which page you find the passage you don't understand.

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry yes, just a moment ...

Comment: Also, the article you linked to gave a quick discussion of the relevant concepts in Section IIc, and refers to References 35 and 36 for background. Have you consulted them first? If so, what are your specific questions? As you can see, reference 36 is **a book**; unless you pinpoint where you don't understand I'm afraid this question would be way too broad to be answered in the Q&A format of this forum.

Comment: @WillieWong I am just rereading the paper after getting an overview to anderstand the details now. I'd rather like to avoid having to read a whole book to understand this article. I thouht this is a relatively easy thing I just dont get. Sure, I can edit in more specific details about what I dont get when I'm at Section IIc again for example. Or should I delete the post ... :-/?

Comment: Please edit in specific details that you don't get. The basic idea is [Paley-Wiener theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), that the (inverse) Fourier transform of an _entire_ function of growth bounded by exponential should correspond to a function of compact support (and hence decays infinitely fast at high frequencies). Thus one expect the presence of high frequency asymptotics to be tied to the failure of the analytic continuation to be an "entire function of certain growth rate". In particular, singularities would be one way for a function to fail to be entire